# jQuery: appended table row doesn't contain CSS styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have a dynamically created table via jQuery, but when a row element is added via ajax request, the newly added row does not follow the CSS styling. Is there a way to fix this?

Below is an example of what I have:

```html
function createTable(data) {
   var row = $('<tr id=' + data.id + '/>');
   $("#table").append(row);
   row.append($('<td>' + data.name + '</td>'));
   row.append($('<td>' + data.age + '</td>'));
}
```

Comment: I'd need to see your CSS and a bit more JavaScript to have a functional example of the problem.

Comment: css is bootstrap, and the javascript is as shown above with just boostrap styling buttons added on the bottom

Comment: Have you applied the bootstrap class for the table?

Comment: Yes. ONLY the last newly appended row does not follow the bootstrap styling. Upon refreshing the page, the style is applied properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
var table=document.getElementByI("table");
var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
var cell=row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
$(cell).text(data.name);
cell=row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
$(cell).text(data.age);
```